# How to prevent Application automatically maximize window at start?

Tags: windows

I have a Application which always maximizes its windows size when it starts. It is a little annoyed. Is any way on windows (I am using win10) to forbid specific application and prevent it automatically maximize its window?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Window's position and size to be remembered, then

1. Open the Window and size and position as you like
2. Holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, click the white X in the red box to close the Window (in the top right of the Window)

Next time, Windows will attempt to load it in the position. Just tested on Chrome and it works. If it doesn't, then the programming is overwritting this!

There is a small gotcha with this, it will only work if 1 instance of the Window is open!